# How do I create an installer that can install dependency software?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

Is it possible to create an installer where the user must install 'x' software before continuing with the installer? For example, if the user does not have the required software to use my own software, the installer will guide them through the set up and download the required software and then proceed to install my software as the final step?

I have never created an installer so I have no idea if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create an installer where the user must install 'x'
>   software before continuing with the installer?

Best approach to handle this requirement is to create a `Bootstrapper package` and add required software as a prerequisite for the main application installer. First you have to install the bootstrapper manifest generater tool from the link i have provided below. Tool will autogenerate necessary manifest files. You have to copy these files to the following folder(Visual Studio2010) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages`.

Once thats done go to your Application deployment project > Properties > Prerequisite There you will see your prerequisite software as one of the prerequisite option. Just select that and create the MSI. Now when you run the Setup.exe of your application it will first check if the prerequisite software package is installed in the target machine if so it will directly install your application otherwise it will first install the prerequisite component and then install your application.

> **MSDN**: The bootstrapper first detects whether any of the prerequisites are already installed. If prerequisites are not
>   installed, the installation begins for the prerequisites. Otherwise,
>   if all the prerequisites are detected, the bootstrapper just starts
>   the application installer.

- [Creating Bootstrapper Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)
- [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567)

Answer (score 0):

As *AccessDenied* said, using a bootstrapper is the best option. Right now the best and most powerful free bootstrapper from the industry is available in [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). It integrates with VS so you can have the setup project directly within your solution, or as a part of your automated build.