# install another in progress

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am trying to create an installer and it will install another *.msi.

But it is failure, because can't install at the same time.

If it is possible to pause main installer and install another msi??

Comment: How are you creating the installer and how are you calling the second .msi?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a bootstrapper package. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020621/how-do-i-create-an-installer-that-can-install-dependency-software/20021466#20021466) post on how to create a bootstrapper package.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a custom action to install something else, and that something else is an MSI-based setup, and that nearly always won't work (without going into gory details) or is a really bad idea.